Add Uploadfile param to FastApi Post request
I have an endpoint that was doing the following:

select an item from a dropdown
set an email address
pick an item from a dropdown and populate the json data you can modify
execute (to send the data to the selected email in step two.
AddON
Now i want to add a file uplaod to this endpoint and attach it to the email that's getting sent.
However, when i add the UploadFile item it changes the content-type to Multipart which is fine but i can no longer select an item from step 2 (basically this step is no longer viable since that was application/json) i know you can't mix the two... is there a way to do this?
below is the code for the post request



@router.post("/send-test")
    async def send_test_email(
        request_body: Annotated[
            MODEL_NAME, Body(openapi_examples=JSON_OBJECT_API_EXAMPLES)
        ],
        
        brand_name: BrandNameChoices,
        send_to: str | None = Query(
            None, description="Defaults to email@domain.com"
        ),
        files: List[UploadFile] = File(),   (when i add this it produces the first image)[This is what happens if the file upload is added in code[THis is prior to file upload param being added](https://i.sstatic.net/l3bdwl9F.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/oTjQEKRA.png)
    ):

I have tried This and also tried to sort out the order which someone says it's because the order of the optional parameter... didn't think that was the case IMO
and also tried this

You can't combine an UploadFile with non-POST / query arguments - so no JSON body.

@MatsLindh i know that part, what are your suggestions if any?

The linked question and answers has a list of alternatives.
